# Как найти номер минимального числа одномерного массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
  int i, n, min;
  int *x=new int[n];
  do /*начало проверки условия*/
  {
    cout<<" vvedite n (n>0) "; cin>>n;
    srand(time(NULL));
  }while (n<=0); /*конец проверки условия*/
 
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
     x[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
     cout << x[i] << " ";
  }
  min=x[0];
  for (i=1; i<n; i++)
  {
    if (x[i]<min)
    {
      min=x[i];
    }
  }
  cout<<" min element "<<min;
  system("pause>>void");
  return 0;
}
```

Минимальное число из массива находит, но также нужно находить и номер под которым это число стоит в выводе

```
cout << x[i] << " ";
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести номер минимального элемента

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас есть ошибки. Я постарался не отходя от вашего решения, их исправить и дописать поиск индекса. Пожалуйста, пересмотрите все изменения и разберитесь, **почему** они внесены (лишнего я не делал).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    //setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, n, min, idx;
    do /*начало проверки условия*/
    {
        cout<<" vvedite n (n>0) "; cin>>n;
    }while (n<=0); /*конец проверки условия*/

    int *x=new int[n];

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        cout << x[i] << " ";
    }
    min=x[idx = 0];
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (x[i]<min)
        {
            min=x[idx = i];
        }
    }
    cout<<" min element "<<min << " at index " << idx;
    system("pause > nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы объяснить, почему Вы idx написали именно в массиве x[]?

Comment: А так короче :) Можно расписать `min=x[idx = i];` как `min=x[i]; idx = i;` — результат тот же.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помогли !